2.5 hours transit time in CDG
I am traveling from Iceland to Tunisia via CDG on unconnected tickets (respectively PlayAir and Air France) and have 2.5 hours and no checked-in bags. I hold an EU passport and I land at Terminal 3 and depart from Terminal 2F.
Do I have any hope to make it? Any input would be appreciated.

do you already have an idea of how long it takes to go from T3 to T2F?

From the YT videos I have watched and from the official maps, it looks like it would take me around 10-15 minutes if I don't make any wrong turns.

@StressedFennec A lot more than that, actually. You're not really departing from 2F but from the L gates. Don't know how fast you walk, but it can take between 25 and  45 minutes + queues for passport control and security.


Do I have any hope to make it?

Yes, definitely, at least if you can check in for the second flight online (which is generally possible with Air France). On the plus side, you won't need to wait to get your luggage or queue to drop it off again and won't have any passport checks on arrival.
You will need to switch terminals (which involve a short ride with a people mover) and deal with security at terminal 2F. Next is the exit passport check but in my experience the wait is typically shorter there than on arrival. You also need to factor in boarding time, the departure gate will presumably close at least 30 minutes before departure time so you really have less than two hours to make it there.
Obviously, as you probably know, there are no guarantees. If your incoming flight is cancelled or delayed, you won't make it and Air France won't assist you. You will lose both the outgoing flight to Tunisia and any return flight or additional leg that you may have booked on the same ticket. You will have no choice but to pay the last-minute price for another ticket or return to Iceland.
All-in-all, for this particular scenario (coming in from the Schengen area, exiting with an EU passport, no luggage), it's not a comfortable connection or one I would book myself but it is far from hopeless.


Do I have any hope to make it?

Sure. Its definitely not hopeless and all things go well, that should work fine and I'm guessing you have about 1 hour of margin.
Unfortunately there are many things that can go wrong and they are inherently unpredictable: incoming delayed or rescheduled, gate not available, train out of of commission or overcrowded, taking a wrong turn (CDG isn't the easiest to navigate), snagged at security, snagged at exit control, etc.
The main problem is that if you miss it, Air France can treat you as a no-show and your ticket is cancelled. If you are lucky they may rebook you (for a fee) but its also possible that you have to buy a new same-day ticket on the spot. This can be expensive and depending on time of day, you may not be able to get one.
Hence my personal minimum transfer time for self connection is 4 hours unless there are mitigating circumstances which can adjust this in either direction.

Thanks everyone for your kind inputs!
Just an update in case it can help others since I timed myself:
Everything that could go right, went right!
My flight landed at CDG with 40 minutes ahead of schedule.
It took me 23 minutes after landing to disembark plus shuttle to Terminal 3.
I ran to the CDGVAL station and that took me less than 5 minutes. The ride itself to Terminal 2 was also just 5 minutes.
At Terminal 2, I ran again towards the 2F section, went through security which was not crowded, followed the signs for the L gates and did passport control where only 2 e-gates were working but there were very few people in line. Once that was done, I went to my gate arriving there with almost 2 hours to spare before take off.
From getting off the CDGVAL to arriving to my gate it took a total of 26 minutes.
In total, from landing in Terminal 3 to getting to my gate (25L) it took a total of 54 minutes.
Overall, luck was certainly on my side and as you have already mentioned, I would not recommend less than 4 hours transit time especially if you have checked in luggage.
TL:DR I made it but I was lucky.

Thank you for reporting back, and glad you made it!

Hope? Yes. Certainty? Absolutely not.

Bad news: You arrive in Terminal 3. That means you'll have to use a bus from the plane to the terminal (and some flights sometimes park quite a distance from the terminal).
Good news: there should not be any passport control on arrival since you arrive from a Schengen Area country and not from one with a high risk of illegal migration.
Good news: you don't have any luggage to wait for (but see below).
From T3 arrivals to T2F, you have:

A 500 m walk (outside, but mostly covered)
At most 5 minutes wait for the CDGVAL people mover
2 stops on the CDGVAL, should take about 5 minutes
A walk from the CDGVAL to your gate between 400 m (unlikely) and 1500 m (see below why)


Somewhere on the way, you'll have to go through exit passport control (but you can use the e-gates) and security
You need to be at the gate 20 minutes before departure at the latest

All in all, if your incoming flight is on time, there are no big surprises, and you were able to get your boarding pass online, you should be able to make it without a problem, though not necessarily with a lot of time to spare (depends a lot on the length of the queues at passport control and security).

Note 1: while you don't intend to have checked baggage, make sure you are well within the allowance for cabin bags. On Play, on the cheapest fares, you only get a 25x32x42 cm/10 kg bag included (must fit under the seat in front of you). Larger carry-ons (up to 25x45x56 cm/12 kg) are only included in higher fares, and may be subject to availability. I don't know how strict Play are, but some LCCs can be very strict on that, and it's easy to end up with your luggage checked at the gate. That can add a very long time in CDG (last time I landed in T3 I had to wait 45 minutes for my luggage -- that would make the connection a lot more difficult).

Note 2: I was surprised to see a CDG-TUN flight departing from 2F, as 2F is now supposed to be only Schengen and the last few times I flew to TUN it was from 2E. But on the flights I could get the info for, the departure gate was actually an L gate. This means quite a long walk through the full length of 2F, then the length of the passageway between 2F and L gates, and then to the gate itself. That explains the maximum distance of 1500 m from CDGVAL to gate. Hopefully they don't go as far as sending you to M gates, that would add another people mover in the mix. I'm not sure what the actual itinerary from landside T2F to the passageway to L is.


You can save a bit of time if you have status with AF and can use the "Sky Priority / Accès N°1" priority lanes for the e-gates and security.
Like the others, I would like to emphasise the fact that if you miss your flight, AF will consider you a no-show, will most likely cancel your flight (and any return flight on the same ticket), and you would have to buy a new one on the spot, which could be quite expensive.
I'm not sure I would take that connection unless I had a very good plan B.
